# How to write nullable properties for EF6 table definition class with C#?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I want to write an C# class to describe a database table with an relation to itself, later to be used with Entity Framework 6.

[image: Entity relation diagram of Contacts table]

I have the following C# code to implement the above shown table:

```
public class Contact
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique identifier of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string ContactId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the contact.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines whether the contact belongs to another contact (e.g.,
    /// parents, organization).
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Contact BelongsToContact { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to mark `BelongsToContact` as `Nullable`, as this property is not required. There may be some contacts that belongs to other contacts, but there are also contact which does not belong to any contact at all. The field should be nullable.

To mark `BelongsToContact` as nullable, I changed the property from type `Contact` to `Contact?` (which is a shorter form of `Nullable<Contact>`).

```
public virtual Contact? BelongsToContact { get; set; }
```

Now, I receive the following error:

> Error CS0453  The type 'Contact' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

So: **How to mark a property as optional/nullable correctly?** The most generic way (without Entity Framework 6 markup when possible).

Comment: Your `Contact` type is a class.  That makes it a reference type.  Variables of reference types are nullable by nature.  You can't make them more nullable (and you can't make them non-nullable).  The next version of the C# language will include something called "nullable reference types", but that's just some syntax and accounting tricks - reference types (i.e., classes) are always nullable.  I just noticed that your `BelongsToContact` is a string in the database.  Strings are classes (and nullable) too.

Comment: Contact is a reference type, all reference types are nullable. Not sure if this will directly fix your issue but I'm pretty sure you don't need the `?` operator after your Type in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
    public class Contact
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Unique identifier of the contact.
        /// </summary>
        public string ContactId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the contact.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines whether the contact belongs to another contact (e.g.,
        /// parents, organization).
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("BelongsToContact")]
        public int? BelongsToContactId { get; set; }
        public virtual Contact BelongsToContact { get; set; }
    }
```